# How to update or refresh the contents of a ComboBox in a WiX dialog?

Tags: combobox, wix

I would like to implement the well-known scenario whereby the contents of a ComboBox in a WiX dialog depends upon the contents of a previous TextBox value, as input by the user. This will allow me to drive the installation of a component that needs to run SQL scripts.

First, the user specifies the name of the database server.

Second, I would like the ComboBox to display the list of available databases on said server.

This seems a simple enough request and, as far as I understand it, is not easily supported with Windows Installer / WiX. However, I would like to workaround and implement this behavior as close as is possible.

What would be the closest implementation possible ?

I have tried an explicit pushbutton that triggers a custom action. I have tried a duplicate identical dialog that gets navigated to but I can't seem to combine two behaviors - CA execution and dialog navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach is this:

- create a custom dialog which contains the edit box control
- create a different dialog which contains the combo box control
- on the Next button of the first dialog execute a custom action which populates the combo box on the second dialog

This cannot be done using a single dialog.

Also, you need to write custom code to populate the combo box. You can find some sample VBScript code here: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-combobox-listbox.html#combolist-examples

It's an example for Advanced Installer, but the sample .VBS custom actions can be used with any setup tool.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However I cannot make this work. Can you elaborate with the solution. I have created two different dialogs, as instructed, which are inserted in the correct order in the UI sequence. On the first dialog, I create a <Publish Event="DoAction" Action="GetDatabasesCA" /> tag under the Next button, but it is not invoked. As my original question states, I cannot trigger *both* the  dialog navigation *and* the custom action.

Comment: Most likely your control events are not configured correctly. The next dialog is displayed by a NewDialog control event which is not related in any way with your custom action. You can try posting your configuration so we can take a look.

Comment: You are correct, thanks. I had my Publish Event/@Order wrong.